# Poor performance of Chrome using background-size: cover

Tags: google-chrome, background-image, css, cover

I need to cover background in my site and I always see **lags/slugs** on mouse over or any other action. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?
I have a working example here (If I didnt update the code yet) : http://natgeo.geryit.com

```
ul#posters li {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears webkit doesn't cache the resized image and renders it every time, causing the lag.

You're out of luck when it comes to background-size in chrome.

I've seen people do it with Javascript / jQuery. See http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/

Comment: Thanks man, Im trying to find a pure css way. I will use jquery if I cant solve.

Comment: It seems that chrome still has this issue to this day. It works just fine on Firefox...