# optimizing images/css for speed performance

Tags: css, image, optimization

I have a background image, 1000x666px, and only 93kb. I use it as a background image, with this code:

```
url(/Optimized-image1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

When i set this image as a background, my jquery effects are very slow and not smooth at all. The same happens with my google maps stuff.

When i set the background just white or any other color, it's all smooth, so I think my CSS-code isn't that good.

I've tried to preload the image with javascript, but that's not good. Also base64 is not working.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `background-size: cover;` performs poorly, at least in chrome.

see [Poor performance of Chrome using background-size: cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869086/poor-performance-of-chrome-using-background-size-cover)

Here's a list of alternative solutions http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: when i delete all that stuff (cover), it's working pretty good! but then another question comes around: when i upload an image, it's has to be "the same" on different screens. So an image of 2000x1000 has to 'scale', I've you know what I mean. It has to full the total background.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can optimize your images with [SMush It](http://www.smushit.com) . Also you can optimize your all CSS files with [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com) .

If you want to 'smush' your images dinamically, you can use Smush It, still.

1. 1) User will upload an image
2. 2) Get new uploaded image's URL ($imgurl)
3. 3) Make a request to
   `http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ws.php?img=$imgurl` and get it's
   content (it's a JSON) to `$content`
4. 4) parse JSON with $newimage = json_decode($content);
5. 5) Your new and optimized image's URL is `$newimage->dest` download
   and use it :)

Comment: thanks for the clean css link. the problem with the images is, that it's a dynamic image. visitors/users can upload their own image. I've an upload limit of 400kb set.

Comment: @yesterday ,  I'm updating my answer just a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried layering your images and dom objects with z-indexes to make sure they arent competing for resources?