# CSS Background image affect jQuery perfomance?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that is approximately 10,000 pixels wide.

As the user scrolls the page moves from right to left, giving a horizontal scroll.

I have multiple divs on my page each with a background image, each div has the background size set to contain so that the image scales the height of each div accordingly.

```
.examplediv {
    background-image:url('myimage.jpg');
    background-size:contain;
    height:80%; 
    width:200px;
}
```

My page scrolls relatively smoothly up until it gets to the point Id have .examplediv, where it then starts to jitter/jerk.

What im asking is, has anybody experienced this problem before, is loading images in the css slower than leaving empty div tags in the markup? is the :contain value recalculating on every scroll and slowing it down?

Comment: are all your images optimized to be the right size for the screen?

Comment: Can you actually show us the page?

Comment: A while back I was making a parallax scrolling site and some of my background images got jumpy. I ended up adding background-position:fixed; and it solved the issue. This was more of a web-kit fix, as it was always smooth in firefox. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that when using `background-size` the browser actually doesn't cache the image so after every event like covering the image with something etc. it has to render it once again - with bigger images it gives a visible lag

**EDIT: here is a ling to similar question [Poor performance of Chrome using background-size: cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869086/poor-performance-of-chrome-using-background-size-cover)**

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure all the images are no bigger then they actually need to be. Also, in Photoshop you can set the quality down quite low for web.

In photoshop use save for web and you can see the old and new image at the same time in the 2up view.